# Windows 10 IOT Core , Normal C++ dll and C# code support?

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

I have a real-time image processing DLL written in C++ based on OpenCV v3 and a C# program with GUI based on that dll. I want to use that dll in Windows 10 IOT core, is that possible? The DLL is using an IP camera to get frames and process them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is Yes, but with some extra work.

You won't be able to use the C++ unmanaged dll directly with Windows IoT Core. You need to create some "wrapper" classes around your native C++ APIs, using pInvoke.

Microsoft has an official github repository fork of OpenCV, https://github.com/Microsoft/opencv, follow the tutorial here to use it with Windows IoT Core https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/opencv

Also, notice that [EMGU CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is introducing support for UWP in the latest revision, however, you'll need to get the commercial license for that.

Comment: Than you very much. i think it's better to improve my question ! i don't need any GUI that's why i'm gonna use windows 10 IOT core , this undamaged c++ dll which i've purchased uses OpenCV v3 and VLC plugin to connect to an IP camera and gets its frames , 25fps , then apply an image processing operation on each frame and then return a result (for example License plate of each car) as text , then i have to save that text in a SQL or SQLite or... database , that's it , i don't need any other services or unnecessary thing , i want all these processes start immediately the OS starts.sorry for Eng